# How to make configuration dynamiclly loading without any profile when using spring-cloud-config?

Tags: dynamic, config, spring-cloud-config

I want to make configuration dynamiclly loading without any profile  when using spring-cloud-config.However,if I don't use profile,the config-client can't fetch config from config-server.So if there's a way to resolve the problem.My English is poor.And thank you for your watching.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slw20.png)

[I try to do that,but failed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cV9uG.jpg)

Comment: Configuration client uses "default" value for profile anyway. Could you please provide more details/code that will describe your problem ? It's hard to help without details.

Comment: Firstly,thank you very much for your attention.The fact is that I want to change the default value from the original code of configuration client.What I want is that configuration client can auto fetching config with my own settings when I start it.I will attach some code/log here.Thank you!